# T-SQL modify column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to modify this column and it doesn't work in T-SQL:

```
create table logininfo
( 
    ID int primary key ,
    modepasse varchar(10) not null, 
)
```

I want to change `ID`'s datatype to `varchar(20)`.

When I use this command:

```
alter table logininfo
    alter column ID varchar(10)
```

it doesn't work.

Please help me

Comment: Why alter column ID varchar(**10**) if you want varchar(**20**)?

Comment: What does *it doesn't work* mean?? Do you get an error? If so: ***WHAT*** error?

Comment: When you run these statements the error *does* tell you the problem. What about the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drop the constraint first before you can alter the column.

```
ALTER TABLE logininfo DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint name>;
```

You can get the constraint name this way:

```
SELECT [name] FROM sys.key_constraints WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('logininfo');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should drop `Primary key` first,
it's better you create your table like following syntax:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS logininfo

CREATE TABLE logininfo
( 
    ID INT,
    modepasse VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_logininfo PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

as you can see you can define `PK` and other constraint after defining columns and named them (meaningful name)
now you must drop pk first then alter the column ID

```
ALTER TABLE logininfo
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_logininfo ;
```

now you can alter the desired column:

```
ALTER TABLE logininfo
    ALTER COLUMN ID NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
```

If you want to use this column as Primary key again you must consider it NOT NULL

now set it as Primary key :

```
ALTER TABLE logininfo
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_logininfo PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```